# Logging in to heroku docker registry from command line

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm trying to log in to registory.heroku.com so that I can push my own images, but I'm having issues authenticating. If I follow the [guidance from the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#logging-in-to-the-registry), I get this:

```sh
> docker login --username=_ --password=(heroku auth:token) registry.heroku.com                                                          2077ms  Thu 29 Oct 09:15:57 2020
 ›   Warning: token will expire 05/07/2021
 ›   Use heroku authorizations:create to generate a long-term token
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
```

So it wants me to use a long-term token. If I generate one using `heroku authorization:create`, and use the generated token as the password then the login is rejected:

```sh
) docker login --username=_ --password="this is a token" registry.heroku.com                                       1140ms  Thu 29 Oct 09:21:23 2020
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://registry.heroku.com/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

Do I need to set a scope on the long term token to get this to work? I want to use long-term tokens as the process is going to be running on CI and I want to configure it via environment variables.

Comment: Dont you want to use the Heroku CLI?

Comment: Not currently, no, I'm trying to create a more portable solution in case of changing hosting services.

Comment: Hey @chooban, I faced the same problem, turns out I was using the id of the token not the actual token, use heroku authorizations:info <token_id> to get the token

Comment: @OmarMneimneh I've just had the same happen to me. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer so we can upvote it?

Comment: I added the answer, thanks @BrunoBrant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem, turns out I was using the id of the token not the actual token, use heroku `authorizations:info <token_id>` to get the token.